# Which Pattern can be used for Authentication and Authorization....c#

Tags: .net, asp.net, winforms, authentication, authorization

## Scenario: -

1) There is trade based winApp in c#. You have to see whether the user is authorized for particular module(macro level authentication).

2) Further you have to check whether authorized user is having sufficient rights to access certain reports/menus / properties etc. (more granular level authorization)

## Question: -

You "have to" use design pattern(s). According to you which pattern(s) is/are suitable for this scenario.

## Constraints:-

you cannot avoid using pattern(s). You have to use standard / custom pattern(s) to achieve it.

Comment: Is this homework? To force the use of design patterns is a bad smell to me...

Comment: Smells like homework...!

Comment: its not an homework, its an question which is being awarded to me in the meeting of expert/designers...but still unanswered by me. I had spent many years in trade application in different module but this seems challenging....not the "homework"...and moreover its a real time scenario. Many trade applications uses there own patterns or combination of two or more standard patterns. so the reason to use patterns is quite obvious. How designers achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use Command pattern to see if the user is entitled to perform particular, if not disable.

Looking at MS Enterprise Libraries might help, I have seen my team use it for authentication stuff (based on roles/groups)